# How to find device using GUID in C++? What changes are needed to get this to build under MinGW?

Tags: mouse, guid

1. GetSystemMetrics(SM_MOUSEPRESENT); is returning true always whether mouse present or not.
2. What changes are needed in code below for MinGW:
   https://stackoverflow.com/users/608884/**noobsarepeople2**
   [Picked this from original thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22995397/is-there-a-way-to-determine-if-a-windows-computer-has-a-trackpad-and-a-mouse-con/23000754#23000754?newreg=918c48ed634d444c92e0f075c5890a0d ] - Answered by https://stackoverflow.com/users/886887/**harry-johnston**